# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: on(...).subscribe is not a function in InAppBrowser's event ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, inappbrowser

I want to use InAppBrowser for oauth2 in my app .
I created a service for this target.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserEvent, InAppBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { AppSettings } from './appSettings';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

constructor( private platform: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser ) {
}

login() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        const url = AppSettings.OAUTH.ACCESS_TOKEN_URI + '?client_id=' + AppSettings.OAUTH.CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + AppSettings.OAUTH.CLIENT_SECRET + '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback&response_type=token&scope=' + AppSettings.OAUTH.SCOPE;
        let browser: InAppBrowserObject = this.iab.create( url, '_blank', 'location=yes' );

        browser.on( 'loadstart' ).subscribe(( event: InAppBrowserEvent ) => {
            console.log( event.url );
            if ( event.url.startsWith( "http://localhost/callback" ) ) {
                browser.on( "exit" ).subscribe(( event ) => { } );
                browser.close();
                var requestToken = ( event.url ).split( "code=" )[1];
                return requestToken;
            }
        }, err => console.log( err ) )

    } );
}
}
```

but on fire loadstart event get error:

```
   Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: browser.on(...).subscribe is not a function
```

why throw this error ?

Comment: have you import in `app.module.ts` file like this `import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';`?

Comment: @hrdkisback  reply: yes

Comment: This method only support run in device not in browser.